# file-name is transparently redirecting to file-name.php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

If I request /file-name I get /file-name.php's content back. I want to know how this is happening but can't seem to figure it out.

I emptied the .htaccess and it's still doing it. I verified that the .htaccess I emptied was the correct one by placing "zzz" in it and that resulted in an internal server error, as I'd expect.

I can't find anything in the httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Apparently [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) is the cause.